# Opengl binding different mipmap levels of same texture2darray for use in compute shader. How to handle variable nr of levels?

Tags: image-processing, opengl, glsl, compute-shader, mipmaps

So I want to make a compute shader that uses a coarse-to-fine approach.

As I have learned about open gl mipmap levels it seems they could be very useful.

However the only binding method which I have found and used (so far) for individual mipmap levels is

```
glBindImageTexture
```

for example the call

```
glBindImageTexture(1, im_mvs, level, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```

binds the level mipmap level of the first texture (nr 0) im_mvs to slot 1.

As far as I know I can do

```
glBindImageTexture(1, im_mvs, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glBindImageTexture(2, im_mvs, 1, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
glBindImageTexture(3, im_mvs, 2, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
```

to bind three different levels at once and then when preparing my program

```
glUseProgram(...);
glUniform1i(Loc_mvs1,1);
glUniform1i(Loc_mvs2,2);
glUniform1i(Loc_mvs3,3);
glUniform1i(Loc_NrLevels,3);
```

and then inside the comp shader;

```
layout(rgba32f, binding = 1) uniform image2D      mvs1;
layout(rgba32f, binding = 2) uniform image2D      mvs2;
layout(rgba32f, binding = 3) uniform image2D      mvs3;
uniform int NrLayers;
...
doStuffLevel0(); // will not assume mvs2,3 are bound
if(NrLayers>1){
    someMemoryBarrier();
    doStuffLevel1(); // will not assume mvs3 is bound
}
if(NrLayers>2){
    someMemoryBarrier();
    doStuffLevel2(); 
}
```

First of all, will this usage be okay?

And then, how can I handle it if I only actually want to use 1 or 2 levels ?

What are the hazards of having an unbound mipmap level? Will it be okay if I am just careful enough to never touch (read or write or do other functions on) it inside the shader?

I suppose I can have an extra variable coding for which of these variables to use and which to avoid. Like "NrLevels" above.

This does seem quite cumbersome especially if I need even more MipMap levels in my pyramid.

Is there some smoother way to do it ?

---

Here is an image describing the application. Estimation of motion in videos. Green lines represent motion vectors for blocks.

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Arrays

Comment: So my variables are uniform. How do I set them outside of the shader? Let us say I have in my shader "layout(rgba32f, binding = 2) uniform image2D images[10];"

Comment: The same as you set any uniform variable, but this time instead setting a single value, you set an array (multiple) values. First you have to get the location, here by the name `"images"`. Hint: you will have only one location index.

Comment: aha! so something like this "GLint v[10] = {my,texture,image,unit,integers,here,...};
glUniform1iv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "images"), 10, v);"?

Comment: Try it, but yes.

Comment: I would have another hint for you: instead of using `glBindImageTexture` multiple times, you could call `glBindImageTextures` only once. In order to create a texture list of different levels (or layers), have a look at: [glTextureView](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTextureView.xhtml) (you'll find a discussion about that topic here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Multibind_and_images)

Comment: But will I then have the option to pick different mipmap levels for each? Hmm texture views, will they help me get only a small part of an image2Darray? It could possibly be useful for speeding up some of my code and saving memory when I get data back from the GPU.

Comment: Yes, the parameters `minlevel` and `numlevels` of `glTextureView` allows you to pick specific levels (or layers). The idea or benefit is that you create the texture views only once and **bind** them with one call, instead of multiple bind calls. How often will you have to create a texture view?

Comment: But can I access a TextureView inside a comp shader and if so with which data type or binding?

Comment: A texture view is a texture. Bind it to a target and access it as you would do with any other texture/image. See: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_views

Comment: I only use imageLoad() and it has no input for mipmap level. Is there some other function I can use which allows for that?

Comment: `imageLoad` loads texels from an image. If you bind a level from a texture with `glBindImageTexture` or alias the levels with texture views and bind those with a single call to `glBindImageTextures` doesn't matter to the shader. _"Just as with samplers, image variables reference image unit indices in the context. These are usually set with a `binding` layout qualifier, but they can also be set with `glUniform`."_ (see: [Images in the context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Images_in_the_context))

Comment: what do you do in the compute shader? can you run it once for each level separately?

Comment: As the variable name may hint "mvs" are motion vectors. I am doing video analysis & processing. I would add an image but I am edit-blocked for some reason. Too many pending edits on site. I could run several dispatches with memory barriers in between but I think maybe there will be unwanted time overhead. Thank you very much for all the help. I will look into ways other than binding.